# Shader from a file, program stopped working

Tags: c++, file, opengl

Following an [OpenGL tutorial](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-2-vertices-and-shapes),

in a part, where it creates a vertex shader, it uses the following method,

```
const GLchar* VertexShader =
{
    "#version 330\n"\

    "layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;\n"\
    "layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;\n"\
    "out vec4 ex_Color;\n"\

    "void main(void)\n"\
    "{\n"\
    "       gl_Position = in_Position;\n"\
    "       ex_Color = in_Color;\n"\
    "}\n"
};
```

I just replaces this code, with my code which brings the shader from a file,

```
string readShaderFile(string FileName)
{
string ShaderString = "";
ifstream shaderFile;
shaderFile.open(FileName);
    while(!shaderFile.eof())
    {
        string tempholder;
        getline(shaderFile, tempholder);      
        ShaderString.append(tempholder);
        ShaderString.append("\n");
    }
shaderFile.close();

return ShaderString;
}

const GLchar *VertexShader = readShaderFile("v.vert").c_str();
```

and BANG!

the code doesn't work anymore. What could be the issue?

the **v.vert** file contains the following code:

```
#version 330

layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;
layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;
out vec4 ex_Color;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = in_Position;
    ex_Color = in_Color;
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the contents of `VertexShader` to verify that it's being read in correctly?

Comment: yeh, printed in the console and everything looks fine. Its c like language, so it should avoid the white spaces. And just toggling the code makes the program runs correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to split the read file into lines, just pass the whole file as it is. Also those '\n' are in the C code, because you can't have ordinary newlines in a C string. You must escape them. But this is not neccesary reading from a file.

And then you have a problem here:

`const GLchar *VertexShader = readShaderFile("v.vert").c_str();`

readShaderFile returns a std::string that goes out of scope and the compiler may deconstrung the string instance right there. You must store the returned string in it's own variable and keep that around as long as you want to use its c_str();

Since this is supposedly on the global scope change it like this:

```
static std::string strVertexShader = readShaderFile("v.vert");
GLchar const *VertexShader = strVertexShader.c_str();
```

Comment: You mean anything that comes out of c_str() that is lost instantly if i dont store it to somewhere else. But here I am using a pointer to point at something that is volatile. That's why const GLchar *VertexShader is not actually pointing at anything. Right?

Comment: @iamcreasy: readShaderFile returns a std::string, but you don't keep it in a variable. The only thing you keep is a pointer to its .c_str(), which remains valid only as long as long the returned std::string instance is not deallocated. However as soon as the scope in which you call readShaderFile called is left, that string instance is deallocated and the c_str()-returned pointer becomes invalid.

Comment: But, as they are in the global space, until my program in terminated, the return string of readShaderFile should be there. So, why should i be afraid of loosing the scope of readShaderFile ?

Comment: Where is that global std::string? The compiler may as well decide to discard the std::string instance, because you never store it in a variable. And the compiler simply can not tell from the c_str(), that the instance must be kept -- see my edit.

Comment: That means I should never point to any return variable of any function. Only point towards something which has a valid allocation.

Comment: @iamcreasy: If the function returns a RAII instance, YES! I thought this was common C++ knowledge. If the function returns a pointer itself, then just keeping the pointer is sufficient of course, you have got nothing else than this pointer, anyway. In this situation you probably also have to call a deallocation on the pointer at some time.

Answer (score 2):

Your function to load the shader should be something like this :

```
string readShaderFile(const string fileName)
{
  std::ifstream shaderFile( fileName.c_str() );

  // find the file size
  shaderFile.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
  std::streampos          length = shaderFile.tellg();
  shaderFile.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);

  // read whole file into a vector:
  std::vector<char>       buffer(length);
  shaderFile.read(&buffer[0],length);

  // return the shader string
  return std::string( buffer.begin(), buffer.end() );
}
```

Also, what are you doing after this line :

```
const GLchar *VertexShader = readShaderFile("v.vert").c_str();
```

?
The temporary string gets destroyed, and the VertexShader contains a dangling pointer. What you need to do is this :

```
const std::string shaderProgram = readShaderFile("v.vert");
const GLchar *VertexShader = shaderProgram.c_str();
// create shader program
// etc
```

Comment: why use c_str() in the line std::ifstream shaderFile(fileName.c_str()); ?

Comment: @iamcreasy because the constructor needs `const char*` See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/fstream/